# patch method in ruby sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra-activerecord

I'm writing a web app using sinatra and activerecord but I can't figure it out what's wrong into my code...if you could just check it and guide me through it would be awesome !!All the models are linked but I can't update information about some books into the database..

RUBY SINATRA CODE :

```
     get '/info/:isbn/edit' do
        @book = Book.find_by(isbn: params[:isbn])
        erb :edit
     end

 patch '/info/:isbn' do
     book = Book.find_by(isbn: params[:isbn])
     book.title = params[:title]
     book.page_count = params[:number_pages]
     book.category = params[:category]
     book.save
     redirect to "/info/#{ params[:isbn] }"
   end
```

ERB PAGE

```
   <form action="/info/<%= @book_isbn%>/edit" method="post">

   <input type="hidden" value="patch" name="_method">
   <label for="">Title</label>
   <input type="text" name="title" value="<%= @book_title %>">
</form>
```

[and this is the error page...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifmOV.png)

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure that your controller sets :method_override to true.

```
set :method_override, true
```

Without it Sinatra won't know what do with `input type="hidden" value="patch" name="_method"`

Answer (score 2):

You are sending your form to the wrong URL:

```
<form action="/info/<%= @book_isbn%>/edit" method="post">
```

URL should be `/info/<%= @book_isbn%>`.

Comment: thanks for that..but it keep giving me the same error just that now it substitutes the :isbn with the actual number...the weir thing is : even if I tried to specify another path , let's say  "get '/info/edit/:isbn' do " (change it for the patch as well) the answer from the server would be "sinatra doesn't know about this ditty Try this:
get '/info/3821284293/edit' do " ..but my path is different!!!! Tried restarting the server..but nothing.. @Uzbekjon